# How do I install this package on my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It says to do:

```
yarn add @bigheads/core
```

Then:

```
import { BigHead } from '@bigheads/core'

const Example = () => (
  <BigHead
    accessory="shades"
    body="chest"
    circleColor="blue"
    clothing="tankTop"
    clothingColor="black"
    eyebrows="angry"
    eyes="wink"
    facialHair="mediumBeard"
    graphic="vue"
    hair="short"
    hairColor="black"
    hat="none"
    hatColor="green"
    lashes="false"
    lipColor="purple"
    mask="true"
    faceMask="true"
    mouth="open"
    skinTone="brown"
  />
)
```

But how do I do it in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: That's a JavaScript, not Ruby, dependency. Do you have a single-page app on the frontend or is it all being done server-side with Rails?

Comment: Its being done server-side, I cant use so :/ Thank you btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. This is JSX code, which is meant to run inside a JavaScript (a different programming language from Ruby) framework, presumably React. I'm afraid you can only use this package inside React. If you feel like dipping your toes into React, you can read more about it on the [React website](https://reactjs.org/), which has some great beginner-friendly docs and tutorials. If you want to create a new React app I can recommend [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app), as the tutorials will tell you too.